# Difference between size() preceding and within a loop

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, compilation, stack

In terms of number of operations, compiling time and good practices, is there any difference by doing

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
```

instead of

```
int size = x.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

If there were no compiling optimization I'd say the latter would be preferable, because it is not calling the function stack every time, it assigns one time a variable and then accesses it instead of calling a function.

Does compiling optimization handle this underneath? Let's say I wanted to optimize the code to the most computationally economic as possible; would it be any different?

Comment: No. Program as-per your intent and let the optimizer do its job. Even if it doesn’t recognize (or can’t apply) the optimization, getting the container’s size is an O(1) operation. The only difference is in readability and maintainability, with the second option being worse on both counts.

Comment: It very much depends on the type of `x`. I could write you a type where `x.size()` returns a random number every time making it impossible to optimize out, but I could also write the following: `struct A{ consteval int size() const { return 5; } }; constinit A x;` which would guarantee the compiler realizes the value returned is always the same...

Comment: You should usually prefer a range `for`.

Comment: A quick look: https://godbolt.org/z/KbT3P1csK

Comment: Unless **profiling** has indicated that you need to tweak the code to make it more performant at the expense of it being less readable & maintainable, prefer readable & maintainable.

Comment: The two are not equivalent: the former can be slower than the later because it recompute `size()` over and over. That being said, most container have a precomputed size and `size()` just return the precomputed attribute generally stored in the object `x`. In this case, any optimizing/mainstream compiler will inline the call to `size()` and both implementation will be as fast (assuming you use proper optimization flags). Beside, note that `x.size()` should return a `size_t` data type which is not equivalent to an `int` on most platforms (`uint64_t` VS `int32_t`).

Answer (score 0):

> Does compiling optimization handle this underneath?

Depends. If the loop content is simple enough, then it may handle it. Otherwise, probably not.

Note that if the loop body changes the size, then the loops are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

> Does compiling optimization handle this underneath? Let's say I wanted to optimize the code to the most computationally economic as possible; would it be any different?

Usually, yes. Compiler optimizations handle the best method.

In your case, clang 13.1.6 produces identical code. I created a `size1.cpp` with your one line for() and a `size2.cpp` for the two line example.

```
% cc -O3 -std=c++20 -o size1 size1.cpp -lc++ ; ./size1 ; cc -O3 -std=c++20 -S size1.cpp ; ls -l size1.s ; cc -O3 -std=c++20 -o size2 size2.cpp -lc++ ; ./size2 ; cc -O3 -std=c++20 -S size2.cpp ; ls -l size2.s ; diff size1.s size2.s
size1 180
-rw-r--r--  1 risner  staff  13298 Sep 15 07:55 size1.s
size2 180
-rw-r--r--  1 risner  staff  13298 Sep 15 07:55 size2.s
435c435
<   .asciz  "size1 "
---
>   .asciz  "size2 "
```

Here are the files:

```
// size1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main() {
    int a[8] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };;
    std::array<int, 8> x = std::to_array(a);
    int z = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        z += x[i];
    std::cout<< "size1 " << z << "\n";
}
// size2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main() {
    int a[8] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };;
    std::array<int, 8> x = std::to_array(a);
    int z = 0, size = x.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        z += x[i];;
    std::cout<< "size2 " <<z << "\n";
}
```